# How can I change the slide effect of a bootstrap slide into fade one?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I tried the following code into my own css file 'style.css'. But it does not work. The slide effect does not change and if I give important to all these css, then the previous slide transition also does not work.

```
 .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
      -moz-transition-property: opacity;
      -o-transition-property: opacity;
      transition-property: opacity;
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
      left: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-control {
      z-index: 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For modals that appear fade rather than slide in to view, try to add the .fade class to your modal markup.

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 ........
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not looking for modal, I'm looking for slideshow. Is there any solution with you how to change the slide effect of a bootstrap slideshow into fade?

Comment: Hmm.. you can check this useful code implementation of fadein fadeout https://github.com/k10gaurav/bootstrap-fadein-fadeout

Answer (score 0):

Did you bind in the Javascript components correctly?

```
<script src="/Javascript/Bootstrap/transition.js"></script>
<script src="/Javascript/Bootstrap/carousel.js"></script>
```

Normally, you also have to give the carousel the "slide" class, to overwrite the effect.

Comment: Ya, I did but the slide effect is not changing into fade one.

Comment: Did you bind the bootstrap.min.css before or after your custom styles?